# Flex 4 VideoDisplay background color

Tags: components, flex4, background-color, videodisplay

Is there anyway I can change the black background color from the Spark VideoDisplay component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set property: `opaqueBackground="black"` - worked for me ;)